# Select multiple parameter in link JSP

Tags: jsp, parameters

I have a multi select list in a JSP looking like this:

```
<td><span><b>Delivered by </b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></td>
                        <td><select multiple name="deliveredBy">
                                <option value="volvo">one</option>
                                <option value="saab">too</option>
                                <option value="mercedes">three</option>
                                <option value="audi">four</option>
                        </select></td>
```

By selecting mutliple entries in the list and submitting the form, the entries have the same parameters. The link looks like this:

> `ReportingArea.jsp?member=fsafd&deliveredBy=volvo&deliveredBy=saab&deliveredBy=mercedes&deliveredBy=audi&calc=two&group1=Butter&Application=`

How can I access the individual deliveredBy attributes selected in the list in my Java code ?

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`ServletRequest#getParameterValues()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterValues%28java.lang.String%29).

```
String[] deliveredBy = request.getParameterValues("deliveredBy");
// ...
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, learn [servlets](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) before it's [too late](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/).

Comment: but I dont want to use the parameters within a servlet. Instead, I want to use it within a normal Java class

Comment: Just let the servlet pass it to the Java class then?

Comment: is it possoble to do that without a servlet? just with a few setters and getters? how?

Comment: Use a servlet based MVC framework which uses javabeans as model. E.g. JSF, Spring MVC, Struts, etc. This only requires drastic changes to the JSP file in order to properly act as a view to the model. E.g. in JSF, you need to replace `<select>` by `<h:selectManyListbox>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] deliveredBy = request.getParameterValues("deliveredBy")

for(int i=0;i<deliveredBy.length;i++)
 System.out.println(deliveredBy[i]);
```